# Out of stack space?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro I made that exports a pivot chart every hour:
but I just got this run-time error saying out of stack space
this is my code:

```
Sub saveFile()
    With Application.ThisWorkbook
        Dim objChart As ChartObject
        Dim myChart As Chart
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        DoEvents
        Set objChart = Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects(1)
        Set myChart = objChart.Chart
        today = Sheets("Date Range").Range("D1").Value
        myFileName = "IRF - Daily Receiving " & today & ".jpg"
        On Error Resume Next
        myChart.Export Filename:="\\syncreon.local\data\Redford\Common\Daily Reports\IRF\Receiving\" & myFileName, Filtername:="JPG"
        On Error GoTo 0
        saveFile
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "saveFile"
    End With
End Sub
```

Anything I can do with this?

Comment: Why are you calling the function recursively?

Comment: Refresh data every hour for new chart values

Answer (score 1):

You are actually calling `saveFile` from *within* `saveFile`, leading to infinite recursion that will naturally run out of stack space eventually.

I'm not sure *why* you're doing that since you also seem to be setting up an event to call the function one hour hence.

My advice is to get *rid* of the explicit call to `saveFile` and simply rely on the `Application.OnTime` to schedule it at a later time.

Comment: You know what, I never even noticed I had that.  Woops.  Thanks, lets see if it works fine now.